# WARN StatusConsoleListener The key MDC_KEY was used in both the string and stack-valued MDC

Tags: log4j, slf4j, mdc

I am using slf4j v2.0.9 and log4j v2.21.1.

The MCD log is working as expected but I am getting additionally this following warning.

**WARN StatusConsoleListener The key MDC_KEY was used in both the string and stack-valued MDC.**

Apart from setting the value for logging, I am also reading the MDC value to get the value so that I could pass it to the next REST request. In the log4j.xml file I am using the following patten to write the MDC value --> %X{MDC_KEY}

In the code I am using

```
public static final String DEFAULT_MDC_KEY = "MDC_KEY";


@Override
   protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException
   {
     try
     {
        //...
        MDC.pushByKey(DEFAULT_MDC_KEY, breadcrumbValue);
        //...
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        //... 
     }
     finally
     {
         MDC.clear();
     }
   }
```

In a different class I am retrieving the value if set.

```
 MDC.get(DEFAULT_MDC_KEY)
```

What could have caused the warning?
Is there any way to suppress the warning?

Thanks,
MH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** You probably want to use:

```java
try (MDCCloseable unused = MDC.putCloseable(DEFAULT_MDC_KEY, breadcrumbValue)) {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

First of all thank you for paying attention to warnings: in my experience it is a rare skill these days.

SLF4J's `MDC` offers two kinds of methods:

- the [`MDC.popByKey/pushByKey/getCopyOfDequeByKey`](https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/MDC.html) methods introduced in 2.x (cf. [SLF4J-531](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/SLF4J-531)). They provide access to a per-thread `Map<String, Deque<String>>`.
- the `MDC.get/put/putCloseable/getCopyOfContextMap` methods from SLF4J 1.x provide accedd to a per-thread `Map<String, String>`.
  Although it is not clear from the Javadoc the default implementation of this map is **distinct** from the context deque map.

In order to implement these functions in the bridge between SLF4J API and Log4j API (cf. [LOG4J2-3583](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3583)) without **extending** the Log4j API, we decided to map both the context map and context deque map to the single `Map<String, Object>` offered by [`ThreadContext`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/javadoc/log4j-api/org/apache/logging/log4j/ThreadContext.html).

That is why both maps are accessible through the `%X{...}` pattern converter.

However, in order to prevent users from mistakenly overwriting an entire stack by using `MDC.set`, we issue warnings when the same key is used in both the context map and context deque map.

To get rid of the warnings **don't** use the same key for methods of different groups. I would recommend using the better supported `MDC.get/put/putCloseable` methods.

**Remark**: as far as I could check, Logback does **not** currently have a conversion pattern that would allow users to display the values of the context deque map. Therefore using the old methods allows you to be independent of the logging implementation.

Comment: Big thanks Piotr for your quick response. I am not getting the warning now. For reading the value I am using MDC.get(DEFAULT_MDC_KEY) and I think its same as MDC.getCopyOfContextMap().get(DEFAULT_MDC_KEY). I also tried MDC.getMDCAdapter().getCopyOfDequeByKey(DEFAULT_MDC_KEY) but it's returning null. What am missing w.r.t reading the value?

Comment: The easiest way is to [look at the source code](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/2.x/log4j-slf4j2-impl/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/slf4j/Log4jMDCAdapter.java). Why do you need to use `pushByKey` instead of `put`?